# JavaFX select item in ListView

Tags: java, javafx-2

Hi I am trying to set focus on an item in a listview. After a user opens a file the item is added to the listview, but the issue I am having is that the listview is not setting focus on the new item that was added. I have to click the item in the listview to set focus to it. Is there a way to have the listview to highlight the newly added item right away in JavaFX 2.1 .

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Assuming that the newly added item has an index of `N`,
Selecting it:

```
listView.getSelectionModel().select(N);
```

Focusing on it:

```
listView.getFocusModel().focus(N);
```

Scrolling to it:

```
listView.scrollTo(N);
```

You can use combinations of these and preferably in `Platform.runLater()`.
Scroll then select:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        listView.scrollTo(N);
        listView.getSelectionModel().select(N);
    }
});
```

Comment: I had the same issue using java 8 and the solution was to run the selection after some time has elapsed once the listView was updated: `FxTimer.runLater(Duration.ofMillis(250), () -> listView.getSelectionModel().select(selectedItem));`