# Autoselect first Item of a ListView in JavaFX

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I created a ListView, but when I open it, no elements are selected. How can I autoselect the first item that get loaded? I'm asking this because I'm trying to create an email client and I need that when the user opens the program the informations of the first email must be automatically loaded. This is my code:

```
public class ListController {

@FXML
private ListView<Email> listView;
private DataModel model;

public void initModel(DataModel model) {
    if (this.model != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Model can only be initialized once");
    }
    this.model = model;
    model.loadData(null);
    listView.setItems(model.getEmailList());
    listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldSelection, newSelection)
            -> model.setCurrentEmail(newSelection));

    model.currentEmailProperty().addListener((obs, oldEmail, newEmail) -> {
        if (newEmail == null) {
            listView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        } else {
            listView.getSelectionModel().select(newEmail);
        }
    });

    listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<Email>() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(Email mail, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(mail, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(mail.getMittente());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT: @Gnas This is my code now, but it stil doesn't works:

```
public class ListController {

@FXML
private ListView<Email> listView;
private DataModel model;

public void initModel(DataModel model) {
    if (this.model != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Model can only be initialized once");
    }
    this.model = model;
    model.loadData(null);
    listView.setItems(model.getEmailList());
    if (!listView.getItems().isEmpty()) {
        listView.getSelectionModel().select(0);
    }

    listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<Email>() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(Email mail, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(mail, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(mail.getMittente());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT2:

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader listLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("lista.fxml"));
    FXMLLoader menuLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("menubar.fxml"));
    FXMLLoader textareaLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("textarea.fxml"));
    FXMLLoader fieldLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("textfield.fxml"));
    FXMLLoader buttonLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("button.fxml"));

    AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane(listLoader.load(), textareaLoader.load(), fieldLoader.load(), menuLoader.load(), buttonLoader.load());

    ListController listController = listLoader.getController();
    MenuBarController menuController = menuLoader.getController();
    TextAreaController textareaController = textareaLoader.getController();
    TextFieldController fieldController = fieldLoader.getController();
    ButtonController buttonController = buttonLoader.getController();

    DataModel model = new DataModel();
    listController.initModel(model);
    menuController.initModel(model);
    textareaController.initModel(model);
    fieldController.initModel(model);
    buttonController.initModel(model);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 603, 403);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: Try here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088612/javafx-select-item-in-listview

Answer (score 4):

You're alreading using `listView.getSelectionModel().select(newEmail)` which is the same method you would use to do what you want. Just call this after you initialize the item list and replace `newEmail` by the index of the first item, which is 0.

```
listView.setItems(model.getEmailList());

// assuming the list is never null
if (!listView.getItems().isEmpty()) {
    listView.getSelectionModel().select(0);
}
```

Comment: Are there any exceptions thrown? Does the list have some items but the first one isn't selected?

Comment: No Exceptions. The list has more than 5 items but no one is selected.

Comment: Can you provide the code where you call `initModel` and what you do afterwards?

Comment: Can you check what `listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()` returns? If it's >= 0 it means it's working.

Comment: Yes, it returns 0.

Comment: @SamoaJoe So it's correctly selected, your problem is something else now

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
listView.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `getSelectionModel().select(0)` But you have to make sure you use it right after you've added the elements to the list.

Comment: nothing new to the other answer, is there? And the OP reported, that it doesn't work in his context. No way to know what's going wrong without him providing a [mcve] but also no reason to duplicate the essence of an another answer ...